# How can I customize the frequency of years on X axis in R?

Tags: r, yaxis

My current code is `data1 %>% ggplot(aes(x= Year, y =` Winning time men`)) + geom_point(colour = "orange")`

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we can't really help because we have no idea what format your data is in, or how you would like the plot customised. Please edit your question to include (a sample of) your data - preferably using `dput(data1)`, and perhaps a description of what you would like changed on your plot. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.